# Redshift Unload With KMS Encryption and Credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kms

Is it possible to write an unload command using the credentials argument and the KMS_KEY_ID argument? I get the following error after running the code below:

```
unload ('select top 10 * from testtable')
to 's3://mybucket/test.txt'
KMS_KEY_ID '123456789'
encrypted
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=ZYZYZYZYZ;aws_secret_access_key=as098dfas9dfa9sd09a8fa0sd';


  error:  Invalid credentials. Must be of the format: credentials 'aws_iam_role=...;master_symmetric_key=...' or 'aws_access_key_id=...;aws_secret_access_key=...[;token=...];master_symmetric_key=...'
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     0
  location:  aws_credentials_parser.cpp:114
  process:   padbmaster [pid=47590]
```

Comment: FYI - DO NOT PUT YOUR REAL ACCESS KEY AND SECRET IN HERE

Answer (score 0):

No. If you use KMS_KEY_ID, then you must use an IAM role or ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. Using CREDENTIALS is not supported.

Note: I find it very interesting that there are two ways to specify access keys. One is supported with KMS_KEY_ID and the other is not. The CREDENTIALS clause allows the use of temporary credentials via the additional "token=xxx" which is the only difference that I see.

I recommend using IAM roles and not specifying your credentials with Redshift statements.

[Authorization Parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

Comment: Does this assume that your KMS key should be in the same account as your Redshift cluster?

Comment: I am not sure. I think that the KMS key needs to be in the same account and same region.